# How can I find my container registry reference in all yml files inside gitlab repos

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab

```
import os
import gitlab
import sys

dockerRegistry = "<azure_registry_server>"


def get_environment_variable(variable_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[variable_name]
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Variable '{variable_name}' was not set", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(99)


def get_gitlab_access_token():
    return get_environment_variable("ACCESS_TOKEN")


def main():
    token = get_gitlab_access_token()
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab("<my_gitlab_url>",
                       private_token=token)

    projects = gl.projects.list(iterator=True, get_all=True)

    for project in projects:

        try:
            default_branch = project.default_branch
#            f = project.files.get(file_path='.gitlab-ci.yml', ref=default_branch) # Working fine
            #f = project.files.get(file_path='*.yml', ref=default_branch) # Not working
            temp_var = str(f.decode())

            if temp_var.find(dockerRegistry) != -1:
                print(project.attributes['ssh_url_to_repo'])

        except gitlab.exceptions.GitlabGetError:
            print(f"No pipeline in {project.attributes['path_with_namespace']}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I achieved finding the references of my docker registry occurence(s) in .gitlab-ci.yml file of each   gitlab repos

I also want to see the references in all yml files like *.yml and its not working in the below method

f = project.files.get(file_path='*.*yml', ref=default_branch)